# How to remotely migrate (a part of) svn repository to another svn repository without adding any hook?

Tags: svn

I want to migrate a part of one repo to another (both are remote) with all the commit history logs.

Tried with

```
svnrdump dump + svndumpfilter + svnrdump load
```

but got the famous:

> svnrdump: E175002: DAV request failed; it's possible that the
>   repository's pre-revprop-change hook either failed or is non-existent
>
> svnrdump: E175002: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision
>   propchanges; ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook

`svnsync` fails with the same error.

I have no access to the target server, so adding a hook is not an option and revision numbers and commit dates are not important.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You must have either access to modifying hook scripts or local access to the repositories on target machine.

Please note that when using `svnrdump dump` you can avoid using `svndumpfilter`. This is because `svnrdump` supports dumping a repository subtree (local `svnadmin dump` does not support dumping a subtree, it can operate on the whole repository only, therefore it requires `svndumpfilter` for filtering tasks).

Comment: Actually, it is possible. In the meantime I found [this project](http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2012/01/svn2svn-copy-and-sync-between-svn.html) which has the option to skip setting the properties.